# how to convert json value to html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, template-literals

I'm fetching a json object that looks like this:

```
{
    title: "My entry",
    entry: "I am a paragraph. I have <em>italics</em> and other styling html. 
             
            I am the second paragraph. 
            
            I am the third graf, here is a <a href='#'>link</a>. "
}
```

then I'm using template literals to append the objects on the page like so

```
    const myJson = out.response.items.map((item, index) => {
      return `<div data-item="${index}">
                  <h2>${item.title}</h2>
                  ${item.entry}
              </div>`;
    });
    content.innerHTML = myJson;
```

the problem I'm having is I want ${item.entry} to observe the html and paragraph breaks from the json. How would I do that?

Comment: What does _"graf breaks"_ mean?

Comment: paragraph breaks <p></p>

Comment: Ok, see my [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67164325/1762224) below.

Comment: You could simply wrap it with `<pre></pre>` tags... `<pre>${item.entry}</pre>`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all newline characters with `<br />` and also format the anchor tag correctly.

```js
const content = document.getElementById("content");

const data = [{
  title: "My entry",
  entry: "I am a paragraph. I have <em>italics</em> and other styling html.\n\I am the second paragraph.\nI am the third graf, here is a <a href='#'> link </a>."
}]

const myJson = data.map((item, index) => {
  return `<div data-item="${index}">
            <h2>${item.title}</h2>
            ${item.entry.replaceAll("\n", "<br/>")}
          </div>`;
});
content.innerHTML = myJson;
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: @StephD Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: the data is coming from a google sheet so I can't change the surrounding quotes of a json value?

Comment: @StephD The data you wrote is an invalid string, the data must be having `\n` for newline.

Comment: the json looks like this in the console https://i.imgur.com/j49EqIL.png https://i.imgur.com/jL4nGHD.png

Comment: @StephD I've updated my answer take a look, you can simply replace the newline characters in your string with `br` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `entry` with the following regex: `/\s*\n\s*/g`

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.content');

const out = {
  response: {
    items: [{
      title: "My entry",
      entry: `I am a paragraph. I have <em>italics</em> and other styling html. 

                I am the second paragraph. 

                I am the third graf, here is a <a href='#'>link</a>.`
    }]
  }
};

const myHtml = out.response.items.map(({ title, entry }, index) => `
  <div data-item="${index}">
    <h2>${title}</h2>
    ${entry.trim().split(/\s*\n\s*/g).map(p => `<p>${p}</p>`).join('')}
  </div>
`).join('');

content.innerHTML = myHtml;
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: thanks! would I look to regex for links/italic/strong tags as well?

Comment: @StephD Don't you just need to turn text between literal line-breaks into separate paragraphs? This does just that. You are setting the HTML value with `innerHTML`.

Comment: I also want to observe styling tags (<strong>, <em>) and links

Comment: @StephD what does "observe" mean in this context? Can you show what your expected output is in your question. If you set HTML, the tags will be displayed. I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var response = [{
    title: "My entry",
    entry: 'I am a paragraph. I have <em>italics</em> and other styling html.\nI am the second paragraph.\n\nI am the third graf, here is a <a href="#">link</a>.'
}];

const myJson = response.map((item, index) => {
  var entries = item.entry.split('\n');
  entries_filtered = entries.filter(x => x != '');
  var entries_html = entries_filtered.map(ent => `<p>${ent}</p>`).join('');
  return `<div data-item="${index}">
    <h2>${item.title}</h2>
    ${entries_html}
    </div>`;
});

console.log(myJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no correct answer, the valid approach will be dependent on your HTML/CSS styling decisions. AS mentioned below, you might replace `/n` with `<br />` tags, `<p></p>` tags, or you might use styled `div`/`span`.